# string' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to write a `NumericHelper.ts` where it returns the regex with configurable fraction digits.

```
export class NumericHelper
{
    public static  GET_DECIMAL_PATTERN: string = (fractionDigits: number = 2) => `^([0-9]*(?:[\.|,| ][0-9]{0,${fractionDigits}})?)?$`;
}
```

And this is returning the error below unless it is casted back to `any`. But why? This function is returning string.

> Type '(fractionDigits?: number) => string' is not assignable to
>   type 'string'.ts(2322)

Comment: Right at the end as string , this error usaually returned when a specific error in return an currently i can't get where is the error , but to overcome it , just add after (ftact... :number = 2) : string => and at end maybe add ...?)?$` as string; sorry for that but i sleepy and can't get much focus, sorry for that and hope it vould help.

Comment: Still same error if cast to string also

Comment: I did a small update to my comment..

Comment: still doesn't work sorry

Comment: Put directly public static string get_.... = ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET_DECIMAL_PATTERN` isn't of the type `string`, it's a function that *returns* a string:

```
export class NumericHelper
{
    public static GET_DECIMAL_PATTERN: Function = (fractionDigits: number = 2) => `^([0-9]*(?:[\.|,| ][0-9]{0,${fractionDigits}})?)?$`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the types set in the wrong place

```
class NumericHelper
{
    public static GET_DECIMAL_PATTERN: Function = // function here
      (fractionDigits: number = 2): string => // string here
        `^([0-9]*(?:[\.|,| ][0-9]{0,${fractionDigits}})?)?$`;
}
```

Personally I think it is cleaner without the fat arrow

```
class NumericHelper {
    public static GET_DECIMAL_PATTERN (fractionDigits: number = 2): string {
        return `^([0-9]*(?:[\.|,| ][0-9]{0,${fractionDigits}})?)?$`
    }   
}
```

[Seeing it in action with the JavaScript output](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=51#code/MYGwhgzhAEByCuBbApgJwJbABLJABzWgG8Aoac6PeAIxE2ggBcxH6BxAUQBUB9AEQ4BhAJIBZAIIAZHgAVxXLhwBKsaAAoAZqjDBWAewB2fdAHN0jCAC5oBpNUIBeaACYAlNaYYDJ4mQr-UZEZ4VANoAAMAPTUAbQAGAFoATgBdACo1AH5LGIAdADoAHwAaQugU%20OSUojjigBIiLR19I1NzCABfDtdMnrrwv3IOihIOkhJQSBgEFAxsXAJUZxJSfypaeiYWdm5%20ITEpWXlFFWsAMXgDXXRDaCdNbWvDYzMLa1tEe1Q7l3cGRi8PgcAD4ItFKqkMtk8kVSuUIdVag0mk9Wq9Ot1epl%20gBuUbjYCGCB6EDIfIgPQmNQzNCYHD4ND5Ti8AQiCTSOQKZSwNSuVwTIkkskUqk0ub0xZM3asg4c47ctQAFj5BMFpPJlOpSFp8wZSylLP27KOXJUvP5hIMxPVIq1szpCzQzgNezZh05Jx5ytcQA)